# TAG name standards in Git

Tags: git, github, alm

Few our our team members are wrongly creating tags and its creating lot of problem.

Can we restrict users from creating or pushing tags with name "develop" in Git?

Comment: shouldn't you communicate with your team members first?

Comment: Creating, no: tag name creation is a local operation that someone does in their local repository, where they have full control of the computer and all the software on it. Even if you had a Git mode that prevented it, they could simply install a version of Git that doesn't prevent it. Pushing, certainly: deny them permission to push at all, for instance. Make them use requests that pass through some gatekeeper (person and/or software).  But as @Raptor said, it makes the most sense to talk to the team members first.

Comment: torek - I am ok if they create tags locally but Is there any way to restrict them pushing tags to remote alteast if the tag name matches "develop"

Comment: a pre-receive hook can be used to block pushing tags.. but this question simply reeks of a communication problem coupled with bad developer habits (why would anyone create a tag named `develop` ? And repeatedly apparently.). Have you tried speaking to the team to find out why they are using tags at all? If you achieve what you ask, there's going to be a long period of developer annoyance where 'I can't push my changes' and related lost trust/good-will. Don't fix with process what can easily be fixed with a conversation :).

Comment: Ours is a large org. Some one created tag with name develop and now its available in all developers local. When ever they push refs this develop tag is coming into remote. We can't make sure every ones local is clean.

Comment: Can we add  pre-receive hook at remote level??

Comment: (I didn't see this until just now - you probably want to `@` individuals so that StackOverflow alerts them to your comment) The only way to install a pre-receive hook directly is if you have direct access to the Git repository. GitHub won't let you put in arbitrary pre-receive hooks, but GItHub already have their own pre-receive hooks in place that provide features like protected branches. Read the GitHub documentation and/or contact GitHub support to get GitHub-specific answers.

Comment: Created pre receive webhook to delete such bad tags incase they are created.